# A server is already running. (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was practicing doing ruby on rails and I accidentally closed Visual Studio code while the terminal and rails server is running.

This is what happened after i typed `rails s`

```
PS C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\folder_name\project_name rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.1.4.1 application starting in development     
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
A server is already running. Check C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/folder_name/project_name/tmp/pids/server.pid.
Exiting
```

Comment: delete your server.pid file in the directory or if your in linux use ps and kill -9  <process_id>

Comment: i deleted the server.pid file. thanks

Comment: no problem at all happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command to kill the server using port number.

```
sudo kill -9 $(lsof -i :3000 -t)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the process id for the rails server port :

   lsof -wni tcp:3000
2. Copy value in PID column
3. Kill the process (for example 14400) :

   kill -9 14400

Answer (score -1):

The user just needed to delete the server.pid file and it worked.